# Need to Copy data from email and paste into google spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, gmail

There was two function wrote in that answer code,  one is main and another one is extract details so its take two function, whenever ran the script its throwing error like getdate() not define so i just make as one function as main, now the data tracked automatically into sheet but its reading only first thread which is unread label. if the label having 23 thread , the first thread only repeating as 23 times. even I Have changed threads.messages(0) tracking only first thread which is already read thread, not read and track unread thread. Could you help me

```
function main(){
  var query = {'q':'label:"Sanmina EDI Failed Concurrent Jobs Alert" is:UNREAD'};

  var threads = Gmail.Users.Messages.list(userId='me', q=query);

  for(i in threads.messages){
    var threadIds = threads.messages[0].threadId;
    var message = GmailApp.getMessageById(threadIds);
    extractDetails(message);
    GmailApp.markMessageRead(message);
    }

    function extractDetails(message)
{
    var dateTime = message.getDate();
    var bodyContents = message.getBody();
    var action= bodyContents.search("Invoice")
    var action1=bodyContents.search("Error")
    var action2=bodyContents.search("Terminated")

    if(action > 0)
    {
      var out="Need to create SR"
      }
    else if(action1>0 || action2>0)
    {
      var out="Need to create SR"
      }
    else
    {
      var out="Printing output file"
      }

    var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
    activeSheet.autoResizeRows(1, 2);
    activeSheet.appendRow([dateTime, bodyContents, out]);

  }
}
```

[enter image description here][1]

Sanmina EDI Failed Concurrent Jobs Alert - subject same name for label

Production Workflow Mailer 
May 26, 2017, 7:30 PM

Request Id Program Name                                                 Status     Requested By
---------- ------------------------------------------------------------ -------- 813511350 Sanmina EDI 850/860 Inbound PO/Change Tabular Report         Warning    NERODRIG

Comment: Could you also share the contents of the email as well? Perhaps a screenshot too. More importantly, the `html` content of the email would be of great help in assessing what could be going wrong here.

Comment: Can you try changing the `if` statement to something like this?
`if (action > 0)`

Basically, the **action** param is an integer value that spits out the index of the search param, should the value exist or throw a -1 value to the variable.

Comment: Hi Sourabh, I Have changed if condition and its worked fine, but not get correct result, since the script get output from last to first email, i need first email alone which is marked unread.

Comment: You are declaring the function `extractDetails` inside the function `main`. Also, you are still calling it from the `for` loop. I recommend you to stick to my original answer. If `message` is not defined is probably because it didn't find any email with that query.

Comment: Thanks, Now im using the answer code,  while run the script getting error **cannot read property 'getDate' of undefined**   using the answer code,                                                                                                       
    Did you mean the I calling from for loop the **extractDetails(message);**                                                            **Should i define message in side of the extraDetails fucntion ?**                                  please give me skype id or any video call to discus about the doubts.

Comment: Hi Jescanellas  , as your code the message calling inside of for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the Gmail API to search the threads:

```
function main(){
  var query = {'q':'label:"Sanmina EDI Failed Concurrent Jobs Alert" is:UNREAD'};

  var threads = Gmail.Users.Messages.list(userId='me', q=query);

  for(i in threads.messages){
    var threadIds = threads.messages[i].threadId;
    var message = GmailApp.getMessageById(threadIds);

    extractDetails(message);
    GmailApp.markMessageRead(message);
    }

  }

  function extractDetails(message){

    var dateTime = message.getDate();
    var bodyContents = message.getPlainBody();
    var action= bodyContents.search("Invoice")
    var action1=bodyContents.search("Error")
    var action2=bodyContents.search("Terminated")

    if(action > 0)
    {
      var out="Need to create SR"
      }
    else if(action1>0 || action2 > 2)
    {
      var out="Need to create SR"
      }
    else
    {
      var out="Printing output file"
      }

    var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
    activeSheet.appendRow([dateTime, bodyContents, out]);

  }
```

In case you only want the last message, use `threads.messages[0]` instead of `i`.

More information:
 [List method](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/threads/list?apix_params=%7B%22userId%22%3A%22me%22%7D)

Comment: i have tries this code and getting error Reference Error: Gmail is not defined. i try to solve it, but not sure what is right step.                                                                          
 var threads = Gmail.Users.Message.List(userId='me', q=query);

Comment: You have to enable the Gmail API in Resources > Advanced Google Services and turn the Gmail API on.

Comment: Thanks for the information. there is two function one is main and another one is extract details so its take two function, so throwing error like getdate not define so i just make as one function as main, now the data tracked automatically into sheet but its reading only first thread which is unread label. if the label having 23 thread , the first thread only repeating as 23 times.  even I Have changed threads.messages(0) tracking only first thread which is already readed, not read and track unread thread. Could you help me.

Comment: I just tested the code again and it works fine. Could you update your original post with your current code? I cannot identify the issue without it.

Comment: I have updated the original post. Please check and help me.